# PHP : Check URL in Excel File

Tags: php, excel

I have excel file that have more than URL, its look like 2000 URL.

I need to check this URL, If URL redirect to: https://example.com/Home/Index remove it from file.

The structure of URL is like:
https://example.com/39188

I see this code but i need it for checking from file

```
$urls = array(
    'http://www.apple.com/imac',
    'http://www.google.com/'
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

foreach($urls as $url) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $out = curl_exec($ch);

    // line endings is the wonkiest piece of this whole thing
    $out = str_replace("\r", "", $out);

    // only look at the headers
    $headers_end = strpos($out, "\n\n");
    if( $headers_end !== false ) { 
        $out = substr($out, 0, $headers_end);
    }   

    $headers = explode("\n", $out);
    foreach($headers as $header) {
        if( substr($header, 0, 10) == "Location: " ) { 
            $target = substr($header, 10);

            echo "[$url] redirects to [$target]<br>";
            continue 2;
        }   
    }   

    echo "[$url] does not redirect<br>";
}
```

How can do it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks so:

- Step 1: Find lib read and write Excel File in PHP
- Step 2: reading file excel -> URL array
- Step 3: Create method common: **checkingUrl(url)** return true/false
- Step 3: Create array: **existArray**
- Step 4: loop array (step 2) call method **checkingUrl(url)**
- IF False (URL redirect) -> push url to **existArray**
- Step 5: write file excel with data **existArray**

**Read XLSX (Excel 2003+)**
https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx

```
if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('book.xlsx') ) {
    print_r( $xlsx->rows() );
} else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}
```

Output

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ISBN
            [1] => title
            [2] => author
            [3] => publisher
            [4] => ctry
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 618260307
            [1] => The Hobbit
            [2] => J. R. R. Tolkien
            [3] => Houghton Mifflin
            [4] => USA
       )

)
```

**Write FILE**

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"demo.xls\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$out = fopen("php://output", 'w');
foreach ($array as $data)
{
    fputcsv($out, $data,"\t");
}
fclose($out);
```

Comment: I can write all code. But You are the one who needs to learn.

Answer (score -1):

You need the file()-function:

```
$urls = file('urls.txt');
```

Comment: and ?? what can do ?

Comment: Nothing, you have to do it yourself, unless you pay me.